# OCaml difference between :: and @

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to append one list to an end of another list. The usual `::` operator gives me the following error:

> This expression has type char list
>   but an expression was expected of type char

in the statement

```
`(createList 0 5 'a')::['c';'d';'e';'f';'g']`
(* the following createList expression returns the list ['a';'a';'a';'a';'a'] *)
```

When I use `@` operator, it appends the list fine; so, my question is what is the difference between `@` and `::`? is it just `@` is used between two lists while `::` used between list and non-list types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` concatenates two lists (type `'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list`), while `::` takes an element of a certain type and "prepends" it before a list containing elements of exactly the same type (i.e. `::` has type `'a -> 'a list -> 'a list`).

You can basically simulate `a::b` by `[a]@b`.

Note that `@` requires OCaml to traverse the first list given to find the last argument of the first list. This takes O(n) time where n is the number of elements in the first list. `::`, on the other hand, requires O(1) time.

Regarding your example `(createList 0 5 'a')::['c';'d';'e';'f';'g']`:

`(createList 0 5 'a')` creates a list holding `'a'`s, i.e. we have type `char list`, and `['c';'d';'e';'f';'g']` is also of type `char list`. Thus, you can only use `@` to concatenate them (see above), and `::` makes no sense (see type signature of `::` above).

Answer (score 1):

`@` is to concatenates `two lists`.

`::` is to add `an element` to the `head of a list`